# robotic arm with servo motor(low cost)

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is it possible to create a robotic arm using low cost servos and an Arduino? Even if the servos do not have the feedback option?

As per this example: [Arduino+Servo(low cost)+Ros](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Servo%20Controller)

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336703/robotic-arm-with-servo-motor(low-cost)/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2019-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes i is possible. you may look at ths
https://hackaday.io/project/164495-a-7dof-arduino-arm-for-ros

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1